# Gitlab-ctl reconfigure is failing

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

While running  `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` I am getting an error:

> Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml]'

and because of that the second error :

> Error executing action `create` on resource 'templatesymlink[Create a gitlab.yml and create a symlink to Rails root]'

I tried to remove existing *gitlab.yml* and tried running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` it threw the same error and did not create the new *gitlab.yml*.

Comment: Have you checked the folder rights? Maybe tested it with `777`?

Comment: As per the cookbook ( gitlab.yml.erb), it creates the file with permission `644`. This file has exact same permission as other files in `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc`